# scp works with /bin/sh default shell, but disconnects with /bin/bash default shell

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, scp

I've recently set up a fairly minimal Debian server (`fail2ban` and `ufw` installed with the OpenSSH profile enabled) with a user with default shell `/bin/bash`:

```
$ grep "$(whoami)" /etc/passwd
nightfirecat:x:1000:1000::/home/nightfirecat:/bin/bash
```

When I run `scp file server.ip` from my machine, I get the following output:

```
$ scp file server.ip
lost connection
```

However, when I change my default shell on the server to `/bin/sh` via `sudo usermod --shell /bin/sh nightfirecat` or `sudo chsh -s /bin/sh nightfirecat`, the `scp` command succeeds.

```
$ scp file server.ip
file                                               100%   16KB 314.8KB/s   00:00
```

The same behavior is observed when running ssh commands: (using ssh to connect remotely works fine with either shell)

```
$ ssh server.ip 'echo foo' # /bin/bash shell

$ ssh server.ip 'echo foo' # /bin/sh shell
foo
```

My `/var/log/auth.log` logs don't seem to indicate any authentication issue, and debug logs from scp don't illuminate the problem. I do have a `.bashrc` file that runs on login, however its first commands are `[ -z "$PS1" ] && exit` to exit on non-interactive logins.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in fact with my `.bashrc` file. The start of the file previously read as follows:

```bsh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && exit
```

The problem was `exit` was quitting out of the shell. Using `return` instead works as intended:

```bsh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

P.S. Credit to https://superuser.com/a/1184787/460089 for this solution.